# Kernelspec error while trying to run PapermillOperator in Airflow

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-kernel

I am trying to execute `.ipynb` file from Airflow in ubuntu WSL using PapermillOperator. But my task keeps failing with error `KeyError: 'kernelspec'`. Looking at other answers from various posts I tried several approaches but it is not working. I have a kernelspec as shown below.

```
yaswanth@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/yaswanth/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

```
yaswanth@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~$ ipython3 kernelspec install
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython kernelspec` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter kernelspec` in the future
No source directory specified.
yaswanth@DESKTOP-TUTMG4J:~$ jupyter kernelspec install
No source directory specified.
```

However launching jupyter notebook from WSL worked but I dont understand why I get kernel error. Can someone help on how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

try installing ipykernel if you don't have it and run:

```
ipython kernel install --name my_env --user
```

It might take some time to show the kernel available